# VARIABLE IN C# cant get the value from html text box

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to search an order on my Data base but i cant reach the text on my input textbox
I have already tried a couple of thing i have seen here and on other sites and the variable could't get the value anyway

Asp.net

```
 <div class="input-container">
     <input type="text" id="txtSearch" runat="server" class="input-field" style="color: black;" placeholder="Pesquisar.."/>
     <button id="btnsearch" class="wrapper" OnServerClick="btnsearch_Click" runat="server"><i class="fas fa-search" style="color:#8b9095;" ></i></button>
 </div>
```

CS

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            var txtSearch = FindControl("txtSearch") as TextBox;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT No_ from [encomenda] where No_= @No_", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No_", txtSearch);


            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (sdr.Read())
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Try to use asp textbox directly?

Comment: @VivekMishra i cant beacuse of the css class im using on the div

Comment: didnt work anyway :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a see a serious of bugs...

First here, the `txtSearch` is not `TextBox`, its `html input control`. So this line returns null.

```
var txtSearch = FindControl("txtSearch") as TextBox;
```

the correct way is

```
var txtSearchInput = FindControl("txtSearch") as HtmlInputText;
```

and then use the `txtSearchInput.Value`

Or you can simple use  `txtSearch.Value` as

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT No_ from [encomenda] where No_= @No_", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No_", txtSearch.Value);


    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (sdr.Read())
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
    con.Close();
}
```